# swr errors for 'suppressHydrationWarning' of null how to deal with empty data of swr

Tags: reactjs, null, next.js, swr

I using next.js with swr my code is:

```
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik'
import useSWR, { mutate } from 'swr';
import { myRequest } from '../libs/auth';
import Axios from 'axios';
interface Props {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    message: string;
}

const LoginForm: React.FC<Props> = (loginData: Props)=>{
    const login_req = new myRequest('post', loginData)
    const {data} = useSWR('/api/user/login', login_req.send)  //delete these line no errors

    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant="h3">
            Login
            </Typography>
            <Formik  onSubmit ={async(values, formikHelpers) =>{
                mutate('/api/user/login', [...data, values], false) //delete these line no errors
                await Axios.post('/api/user/login', values)
                alert(JSON.stringify(values))
                formikHelpers.setSubmitting(false)
            }}
            initialValues={{ username: '', password:'' }}
            >
                <Form>
                    <label htmlFor="message"></label>
                    <label htmlFor="username">email:</label>
                    <Field name="username" ref ></Field>
                    <label htmlFor="password">password:</label>
                    <Field name='password' type="password"></Field>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
        </>  
    )

}

export default LoginForm
```

the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'suppressHydrationWarning' of null
```

I think that is my request will sending null as response for people do not initialization the username at the loading time.

Is there any way to deal with empty input of swr hook?

Comment: It seems that you have an empty `ref` here: `<Field name="username" ref ></Field>`.